# Is the binary format the default java serialization format?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

Is the binary format the default deserialization format in Java ? If so does that mean that we do not need any library in order to serialize/deserialize?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "default serialization format" but Java does support binary serialization out of the box: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yes.

Comment: @shmosel  I mean there are other formats such as JSON and XML, how are they different from the binary serialization formats specifically when using Java.

Comment: They have nothing in common.

Comment: It also depends on the context in which you want to use serialization. You should definitely avoid default Java serialization for data which might be in any way controlled by an external user, see [Secure Coding Guidelines for Java SE](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/seccodeguide.html#8). (Also note that Java serialization is not very efficient in some cases, especially for some JDK classes where the JDK tries to remain backward compatible by serializing redundant data.)